# How to use Nullstellensatz to prove Study’s lemma

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a algebraically closed field and $f,g\in k[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$
be polynomials. Assume $f$ is irreducible.

I want to prove that $V(f)\subseteq V(g)$ if and only if $f\mid g$ by using Nullstellensatz. One direction seems obvious and for the other direction I really have no idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I really have no idea.

You just have to take the ideals which are associated to the sets $V(f)$ and $V(g)$. And the strong version of the Nullstellensatz tells us that
$$I(V(f)) = \sqrt{(f)} \quad \text{and} \quad I(V(g)) = \sqrt{(g)}.$$
Since applying $I(\cdot)$ inverts inclusions we get
$$g \in \sqrt{(g)} \subset \sqrt{(f)},$$
i.e. some power of $g$ is contained in the principal ideal $(f)$, say $f \mid g^k$ for some $k \in \mathbb N$. And since $f$ is irreducible, this implies $f \mid  g$.